# How do I set an attribute on an object in Groovy

Tags: python, groovy

I would like to write the equivalent of this Python code in Groovy:

```
>>> class A(object): pass 
>>> a = A()
>>> name = os.name
>>> setattr(a, name, "some text")
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x10aad6a10>
>>> a.posix
'value'
```

I tried this:

```
class TmpClass {}
def tmp = new TmpClass()
String name = getNameFromSomeWhere()
tmp.metaClass.setAttribute(tmp, name, "value")
```

But it throws an exception saying the attribute is not found.

Edit:  I've updated the code to reflect the fact that the property/attribute name is not a literal.

Comment: Are you trying to add a new property?

Comment: The simple answer is I'm unsure!  I want to reference 'name' as tmp.name later on in the code.  "name" and "value" are strings coming from external data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for a way to set dynamic properties, then the square bracket notation should be enough:

```
tmp['name'] = 'value'
tmp[propertyName] = propertyValue //runtime property name and value
```

But if you also need to dynamically grow the object with new fields, etc., and don't want to use a simple map, then you should probably use an [Expando](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.1/html/api/groovy/util/Expando.html) (instead of a class), which supports adding dynamic properties and closures:

```
def tmp = new Expando()
tmp['name'] = 'value'
tmp[propertyName] = propertyValue //runtime values
```

Comment: So I prefer the tmp.setProperty() when using Expando which does the same thing but is IMHO clearer, but it seems Expando is what I want in the end.  There seems to be no easy equivalent of the Python code starting with a blank object and adding to it.  Pity I went down the rabbit hole of mucking about with metaClass.  I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
class TmpClass {}
def tmp = new TmpClass()
tmp.metaClass.name = "value"
```

Comment: Yeah, something like this, but with name as a String variable?

Comment: the type of the 'name' property is inferred by the assigned value. in this case it is a string, yes.

Comment: Please see my getNameFromSomeWhere() function in my edited question, that should make things clearer.  It's the name of the property which is in a string.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the something like this:

```
class Student {
    private int StudentID;
    private String StudentName;

    void setStudentID(int pID) {
        StudentID = pID;
    }

    void setStudentName(String pName) {
        StudentName = pName;
    } 

    int getStudentID() {
        return this.StudentID;
    }

    String getStudentName() {
        return this.StudentName;
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        Student st = new Student();
        st.setStudentID(1);
        st.setStudentName("Joe");

        println(st.getStudentID());
        println(st.getStudentName());    
    } 
}
```

You need to have `name` as instance variable of type `String`. Also, You need to declare setter and getter methods to set and get the attribute also.